# How to split a vector according to a function in Julia?

Tags: julia

In Julia, the `findall(f,v)` function gives me the collection of elements in a vector where `f` applied to the element is true. For example, `findall(iseven,[1,2,3])` returns `[2]`. Now is there a function implemented in base (or a simple implementation) where I actually get the split vector instead of only the true instances? I mean, something like `partition(iseven, [1,2,3])` returning `([2],[1,3])`.

I can do a naive implementation, but I'm looking for a something efficient, preferably an existing function in Base...

Comment: something "naive" would be `partition(fn, seq) = ([x for x in seq if fn(x)], [x for x in seq if !fn(x)])` and how efficient it becomes depends on what the compiler makes of it -- one could also call it "filter", or even "groupby", as a generalization beyond boolean. for dataframes, they have this: https://juliadatascience.io/groupby_combine

Comment: note: findall() gives you those *indices*, not the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be:

```
separate(p, x) = ( t = findall(p, x); 
  (@view(x[t]), @view(x[setdiff(eachindex(x), t)])) )
```

and with `separate` you can do:

```
julia> x = [1,2,3,5,6];

julia> separate(iseven, x)
([2, 6], [1, 3, 5])

julia> E, O = collect.(separate(iseven, x))
([2, 6], [1, 3, 5])

julia> E
2-element Vector{Int64}:
 2
 6
```

Without `collect.` the function returns views which are good if copying the original vector is expensive.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something very fast, try the `groupby(fn,x)` function below. The function allocates a vector similar to `x` and returns views to that vector. It traverses the original vector only once, inserting in the first group the elements of `x` for which `fn` gives `true` and the other elements in the second group.

```
function groupby(fn, x)
    g = similar(x)
    i, j = 0, -1
    for e in x
        if fn(e)
            g[i+=1] = e
        else
            g[end-(j+=1)] = e
        end
    end
    @views g[1:i], reverse(g[i+1:end])
end

x = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6];

groupby(iseven, x)
([2, 6], [1, 3, 5])
```

For comparison,

```
x = rand(1:1000, 1000)
@btime separate(iseven, $x) # 42.100 μs (20 allocations: 34.66 KiB)
@btime groupby(iseven, $x)  #  1.380 μs (2 allocations: 12.12 KiB)
```

Answer (score 0):

If speed is really essential, then a mutating version will be able to take less time and memory resources. For example:

```
function separate!(p::F, x) where {F <: Function}
    b, e, L = firstindex(x), lastindex(x), length(x)
    L == 1 && (return p(x[b]) ? (x, eltype(x)[]) : (eltype(x)[], x))
    L == 0 && return (eltype(x)[], eltype(x)[])
    while b < e
        p(x[b]) && (b += 1; continue)
        p(x[e]) || (e -= 1; continue)
        x[b], x[e] = x[e], x[b]
    end
    @view(x[begin:b-1]), @view(x[b:end])
end
```

is 2x times faster than the other version. To preserve the original vector, `separate!(p, copy(x))` can be used. The benchmarks for the different answers are:

```
x = rand(1:1000, 1000);

@btime separate(iseven, $x); # One-liner
#  14.447 μs (20 allocations: 34.98 KiB)

@btime groupby(iseven, $x); # AboAmmar's
#  1.277 μs (2 allocations: 11.81 KiB)

@btime separate!(iseven, y) setup=(y = copy(x));
# 479.990 ns (1 allocation: 96 bytes)
```